# Bing API News search for Trending topics returns Error 403 Forbidden and code 'InsufficientAuthorization'

Tags: http-status-code-403, bing, azure-cognitive-services, bing-api

I recently tried to search for Trending topics news using Bing Search API v7.0 with a valid subcription key but in response I got the following:

> "code": "InsufficientAuthorization",
>
> "message": "Insufficient authorization to access requested resource.",

I did not face any problem with the Search endpoint, or when using v5.0 API to get Trending topics news.

Comment: I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work now. It seems there was a bug from server side. Here is the link for easy reference: https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/e5e22123c5d24f1081f63af1548defa1/operations/56c7a9a6cf5ff801a090fbdc